# Google testing: как обработать исключения из SetUp() / TearDown()? - C++

Tags: c++, исключения, юнит-тесты, gtest, деструктор

Например я хочу проверить умный указатель. И убедится что локальный объект уничтожается при выходе 
из своего поля видимости:

```
#include  <stdexcept>
#include  <iostream>
#include  <memory>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"


class FooTest: public ::testing::Test {
public:

    void SetUp() {}


    void TearDown() {
        std::cout << mMsg << " deleted" << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error(mMsg);
    }

    void SetLog(std::string msg) {
        mMsg = msg;
    }

    void TestBody() {}
private:
    std::string mMsg;
};

 // Проверяю генерится ли исключение
TEST_F(FooTest, TestExistException) {
    EXPECT_ANY_THROW(
        {
            std::shared_ptr<FooTest> shrPtr(new  FooTest());
            shrPtr = std::make_shared<FooTest>();
            shrPtr->SetLog("local object");
        }

    );
}

std::shared_ptr<FooTest> shrPtrOther(new  FooTest());
// Проверяю содержание сообщения
TEST_F(FooTest, TestLogException) {
    shrPtrOther = std::make_shared<FooTest>();
    shrPtrOther->SetLog("other object");

    try {

        { // begin scope of shrPtr
            std::shared_ptr<FooTest> shrPtr(new FooTest());
            shrPtr = std::make_shared<FooTest>();
            shrPtr->SetLog("local object");
        } // end scope of shrPtr

    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        EXPECT_EQ(e.what(), (std::string )"local object");
    }
}
```

В консоли получаю:

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from FooTest
[ RUN      ] FooTest.TestExistException
../src/testDel.cpp:44: Failure
Expected: { std::shared_ptr<FooTest> shrPtr(new FooTest()); shrPtr = std::make_shared<FooTest>(); shrPtr->SetLog("local object"); } throws an exception.
  Actual: it doesn't.
 deleted
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "" thrown in TearDown().
[  FAILED  ] FooTest.TestExistException (18 ms)
[ RUN      ] FooTest.TestLogException
 deleted
unknown file: Failure
C++ exception with description "" thrown in TearDown().
[  FAILED  ] FooTest.TestLogException (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from FooTest (152 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (154 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 2 tests, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] FooTest.TestExistException
[  FAILED  ] FooTest.TestLogException

 2 FAILED TESTS
```

Основной вопрос заключается в том, как обработать исключения из 
 TearDown() ("деструктора"), с целью  автоматизировать проверку возникающих сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно используете fixture. Их смысл в том, чтобы подготавливать / подчищать данные для теста избегая тем самым копипасты в каждом тесте. Самостоятельно создавать экземпляры таких классов не следует. Метод `TearDown` предназначен для потенциально кидающей исключения подчистки тестовых данных, чтобы избежать исключений в деструкторе. В этом методе не следует продолжать сам тест, или, тем более, специально кидать исключения.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы правы, я напрасно самостоятельно создаю экземпляра  класса фикстуры. Но все таки хотелось бы увидеть пример как  обрабатываются, и есть ли вообще возможность обработать исключение брошенное в TearDown.

Comment: Данная задача пришла мне в голову на основании следующего высказывания: 
> "Вы можете освобождать ресурсы с помощью метода TearDown  или с помощью функции деструктора. Однако если вы хотите использовать обработку исключений, вы должны делать это только через метод TearDown, поскольку вызов исключения в деструкторе может привести к непредсказуемым результатам."
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-googletestingframework/index.html

Comment: @user2421061 Как я уже написал выше, метод `TearDown` предназначен для потенциально кидающей исключения подчистки тестовых данных, а не для проверки кидания исключений. Это не часть теста, и выброшенные там исключения (которых вообще-то не должно быть) обрабатываются, так, как захочется рантайму googletest.

Comment: Понятно, благодарю за ответ!